# Fire Jquery change event programmatically .change() vs .trigger('change')

Tags: javascript, jquery

When programmatically triggering a change event in Jquery after updating the value, you can do either

```
$("input").val("A").change();
```

or

```
$("input").val("A").trigger("change");
```

Is there a reason to use one over the other. Are there any situations in which is more suitable than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood calling `change()` ends up calling `trigger('change')` anyway. But also with trigger you can limit the call to a namespaced event handler for that event (e.g. `trigger('change.myplugin')`), so I just prefer to stick with trigger every time.

Answer (score 2):

They are *exactly* the same. `change()` - and all the other shorthand event methods - uses `trigger('change')` internally ([source](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.change)).

In this specific case the only reason to choose one over the other is your preference of the semantics.

Comment: They are not "exactly" the same. change() has an extra code in which it ultimately calls trigger("change").

Comment: @EmrahIzci exactly... that's the same then. If you're worried about the couple of milisecond delay from running the logic through a ternary expression, then you probably shouldn't be using jQuery.

Comment: As you said, they have milisecond level difference in performance aspect, which doesn't make them "exactly" the same. But yes I am crashing atoms so miliseconds are making me deny that they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

They have the same functionality, but are not exactly the same. So here is the source code for change():

```
 function (a,c){
      c==null&&(c=a,a=null);
      return arguments.length>0?this.on(b,null,a,c):this.trigger(b);
 }
```

So change() has a conditional statement which calls trigger('change') as a result of it. Thus, trigger('change') works slightly faster.